# edit grid in admin section is not showing

Tags: admin, grid, controllers, grid-serlization, configuration

I have a grid from a custom module in my admin section which displays users that fit a specified criteria. When I click on one of those users to edit details I am transferred to a blank content area where I would expect to see a form.

I have gone over my code and what I understand to be correct and have changed the _blockGroup to = [module], [namespace], [module_namespace] but don't have any success.

```
class Ps_Prefs_Block_Adminhtml_Prefs_Edit
extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form_Container
{
public function _construct()
{
    parent::_construct();

    $this->_objectId = 'id';
    $this->_blockGroup = 'prefs';
    $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_prefs';
    $this->_mode = 'edit';
}
```

config.xml

```
<config>
.......
    <admin>
    <routers>
        <adminprefs><!--arbitary name but needs to be unique-->
            <use>admin</use>
            <args>
                <module>Ps_Adminprefs_AdminprefController</module>
                <frontName>admin</frontName><!--admin works!but all other custom admin modules fail! adminPrefs produce 404! -->
                <modules>
                    <Ps_Prefs after="Mage_Adminhtml">Ps_Prefs_Adminhtml</Ps_Prefs>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminprefs>
    </routers>
</admin>
........
</config>
```

adminhtml.xml

```
<config>
<menu><!--adds menu item called prefs > example onto the admin menu bar-->
    <customer>
        <children>
            <Prefs translate="title">
                <title>Prefs Centre</title>
                <sort_order>90</sort_order><!--sets the prefs towards the end of the list-->
                <action>adminhtml/adminprefs</action>
            </Prefs>
        </children>
    </customer>
</menu>
........    
<layout>
    <updates>
        <prefs>
            <file>prefs.xml</file>
        </prefs>
    </updates>
</layout>
```

Ps_Prefs_Adminhtml_AdminprefsController

```
public function editAction()
{
    $model = Mage::getModel('prefs/prefs');
    Mage::register('prefs_data', $model);
    $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');

    try {
        if ( $id ) {
            if ( ! $model->load($id)->getId() ) {
                Mage::throwException($this->__( 'No record with that ID "%s" found', $id ));
            }
        }

        if ( $model->getId() ) {
            $pageTitle = $this->__('Edit %s (%s)', $model->getName(), $model->getType());
        } else {
            $pageTitle = $this->__('New User');
        }

        $this->_title($this->__('Customer'))
             ->_title($this->__('Preference'))
             ->_title($pageTitle);

        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();
    }   

    catch (Exception $e) {
        Mage::logException($e);
        $this->_getSession()->addError($e->getMessage());
        $this->_redirect('*/*/');
    }
}
```

I believe it is in the edit file but I have added the other files incase it helps with a solution.

===

EDIT

===

the problem was with the config. The below works

```
<admin><!--new way to define an admin route-->
  <routers>
     <prefsadminhtml>
        <use>admin</use>
        <args>
            <module>Ps_Prefs_Adminhtml</module>
            <frontName>admin</frontName>
           <modules>
              <syntax after="Ps_Prefs_AdminprefsController">Mage_Adminhtml</syntax><!--what is this syntax node mean? -->
              <prefsmodule before="Mage_Adminhtml">Ps_Prefs_Adminhtml</prefsmodule>
           </modules>
        </args>
     </prefsadminhtml>
  </routers>
```

Comment: can you post the url you end up with on the blank page?
Also, the way you are defining the admin router, although not wrong, is a dated, less preferred way. See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15349319/how-to-add-magento-admin-router-correctly-to-avoid-conflicts-between-extensions as well as the explanation by Alan Storm located here: http://alanstorm.com/magento_dispatch_admin_cms_default_routers

Comment: the url is http://magentodevtest.local/index.php/admin/adminprefs/ And thanks for that link re: the updated way of defining a router, it answers my confusion on the difference in some tutorials

Comment: Do you still get the same issue if you chnage how the router is done? In your router configuration you are using `<frontName>admin</frontName>`, which could/would clash with magento normal admin functionality.

Comment: So i've changed the router configuration and it has worked although the frontName is still admin. I wont be adding an answer as I have no idea how it has worked, I will update my post with what has worked, any answers as to why will be helpful

Comment: Hi, where did you come across that syntax for the admin router? never seen it done like that before, and never seen the 'syntax_after' tag before. It looks really over complicated. refer to this post: http://alanstorm.com/magento_admin_hello_world_revisited, specifically the section 'Setting up the Admin Controller'

Comment: To be honest Ive lost track of tut i've reviewed and things i've just randomly tried. I would guess that may be a combination of the two. I originally had used that tutorial and it worked. I have since changed something somewhere and that way is no longer works on this module.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thought maybe I could learn something new here :( the syntax after tag intrigued me

Comment: I have found where I got the syntax node tutorial from, as guessed, it was a combination of a genuine tut and me making something up, anyway here is the link http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/coffeefreak-blank-magento-extension-for-building-main-admin-menu-with-sidebar-and-tabs/

Comment: @tony09uk feel free to post the complete working code as an accepted answer to your question

Answer (score 2):

To set up an admin router you can use the following snippet, it should be enough to have these few lines and a controller to get your admin router working:

```
<admin>
     <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <your_module after="Mage_Adminhtml">Your_Module</your_module >
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
```